# Is there any way to play video on an iphone from a website, without using youtube or a custom app?

Tags: iphone, video

I'd like website viewers to be able to play a video on an iphone, without posting the video to youtube, and without them having to install any iphone apps.  Are there any other options here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you host a Quicktime movie, it'll play just fine without any additional software. There is a "designing web pages for the iPhone" document somewhere on Apple's web site that gives more detail on supported formats, I think.

Answer (score 0):

just having a link to a quicktime-playable video file works I believe